# LINQ statement unable to create a constant value of type

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

Ok I have an error from this LINQ statement which I HAVE tested in LinqPad and it works fine. The error is:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'HostelApp.Models.bookingLines'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

The code is here:

```
var availableFBunks = from b in this.bunks
      where b.gender == "F" && 
           !this.bookingLines.Any(
                l => (l.bunkID == b.bunkID) && (l.date == DateTime.Today.AddDays(i)))
      select b;
```

SQL Statement:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = 'F'
DECLARE @p1 DateTime = '2013-11-07 12:00:00 AM'
-- EndRegion

SELECT b.bunkDesc AS Bunk_Name
FROM bunks AS b
WHERE (gender = @p0) AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM bookingLines AS l
     WHERE l.bunkID = b.bunkID and (l.date = @p1))
```

Comment: can you please include the class definition, also try this `bunks.Where(b => b.varname <conditions>)`, also if you could explain what this LINQ statement is meant to do that would be great.

Comment: `bunks.Where(b => b.gender == "F" && (!this.bookingLines.Any(l => l.bunkID == b.bunkID && l.date == DateTime.Today.AddDays(i)))`

Comment: Your linq statement looks fine as far as linq syntax goes but there are some limitations on how you can use linq to query your datasource with Entity Framework.

Comment: I jumped out of bed cause it is bugging me! Its 4am! lol, Matthew thanks I will respond more in the morning, but I tried doing what you said and it wouldn't allow me.

Geezer498, It's bugging me cause like I said I have tested it in LinqPad and it works fine!

Comment: The Linq statement is pulling data from 2 tables, I want a list of bunks that don't equal a date that has been entered. The trouble I have been having is if the BunkID has no entry in the BookingLines table then they never show in the var, so I end up with a black var.

I have added the SQL example as well

Comment: Try pulling out the `DateTime.Today.AddDays(i)` part and putting it in a variable above the query... Since this is a non-determistic statement perhaps it could be to do with the conversion of that... ?

Comment: Didn't spot that from previous edits @Reddog, I had the variable there for it!! I have made the change but still getting the same error :(

Comment: Side note: for future posts try to avoid unrelated text like "thank you notes", "new here" and all sort of sad stories of your life.

Answer (score 0):

You can do IN/NOT IN queries in LINQ using the `let` keyword

```
var availableBunks = from bunk in bunks
        let bl = from bookingLine in bookingLines
            where bookingLine.Date == DateTime.Today.AddDays(d)
            select bookingLine.BunkId
        where bunk.Gender == "F" && !bl.Contains(bunk.BunkId)
        select bunk;
```

[let clause (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383976.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan, once again through the LinqPad it is accepting (after minor variable changes for it to accept it) but as soon as it is placed in the app I get exactly the same error as before :(

Comment: I have got a professional in Uni looking at it, cause they can't see what's wrong with it the code you gave me she said should have worked!! I will post as soon as I know.